# How to get rid of 'quot' in Python json.dumps

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

In Django, I have a view that requests a JSON feed and renders the response along with a template. I need to convert the JSON object to a Javascript JSON object. I have managed to console.log the JSON object in my template, but something is wrong with the format.

This is what I expect:

```
{"lat": 58.548703, "referenceTime": "2013-12-05T07:00:00Z", "lon": 16.155116...
```

and this is what I get:

```
{&quot;lat&quot;: 58.548703, &quot;referenceTime&quot;: &quot;2013-12-05T07:00:00Z&quot;, &quot;lon&quot;: 16.155116...
```

Here is my view:

```
def myView(request):
    request = Request('http://somedomain/somefeed.json')

    response = urlopen(request)
    data = json.load(response)
    return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', {'myJson': json.dumps(data)})
```

And in my template:

```
console.log('{{myJson}}');
```

Comment: So maybe you should show the template?

Comment: Also, why would you bother deserializing from JSON only to serialize it again immediately? What's the point?

Comment: use `{{myJson|safe}}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the snippet from my template.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Armance says in the comments, you need to mark the variable as safe in the template so it is not escaped:

```
{{ myJson|safe }}
```

Comment: Perfect! That solved the problem. For future reference, this is what I had to do in my Javscript: `console.log(JSON.parse('{{ myJson | safe }}'));`

Comment: Yes, because "safe" template filter is used for rendering html tags in django templates

Comment: In my case, I didn't need to parse it after delivery to the front-end. Javascript recognized it as an object.